# python: insert a character 2 positions after every subtring

Tags: python

I have this string: `'51.6251.8750.6951.4651.462626200'`, and want to get a list like this: `['51.62', '51.87', '50.69', '51.46', '51.46', '2626200']`

So, basically after find a dot, the string should be split 2 positions later.

For now, I have the following, where I created a list of all dot positions, not sure if that's the way.

```
import re

string = '51.6251.8750.6951.4651.462626200'

k = 2

# I couldn't find the position of the dot actually, so I had to replace for something first, it may be unecessary

subString = '-'

replacedString = re.sub('[.]', subString, string)

# create a list with all positions of the substring

subStringPosition = [i.start() for i in re.finditer(subString, replacedString)]

# add k to each element of the subStringPosition

subStringAfterK = [x + k for x in subStringPosition]
```

I'd appreciate if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex methods to achieve this result `split` and `findall` with the expiration of `\d{2}\.\d{2}` that is 2 digits followed by . and another 2 digits.
In `findall` it will return all the 2 numbers and 2 numbers after the . and in the `split[-1]` it will return the rest of the string.

```
string = "51.6251.8750.6951.4651.462626200"
result = re.findall(r"\d{2}\.\d{2}", string)
result.append(re.split(r"\d{2}\.\d{2}", string)[-1])
print(result)
```

Output

```
['51.62', '51.87', '50.69', '51.46', '51.46', '2626200']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# string = '51.6251.8750.6951.4651.462626200'
matches = re.split(r'(?<=\.\d{2})', string)
```

Explanation:

*Positive Lookbehind `(?<=\.\d{2})`*

- `\.` matches the character `.`
- `\d{2}` matches a digit exactly 2 times

Result:

```
#print(matches)
['51.62', '51.87', '50.69', '51.46', '51.46', '2626200']
```

You can test the regular expression [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/7RHdrB/1).

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that doesn't use `re`:

```py
def split(s):
    nums = []
    while "." in s:
        i = s.find(".")
        n = s[:i+3]
        s = s[i+3:]
        nums.append(n)
    if s:
        nums.append(s)
    return nums
```